# Facebook shares wrong image/thumbnail

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a problem when sharing a post on our social microblog www.legendaily.com that the share-image on facebook is wrong - it takes 3 images, the first (which 99% will share) is an empty image, the 2nd is our logo and only the 3rd is the one we reference in the `og:image`-tag.
I searched here and on Google but did not find anything apart from "use og:image - which we already do.

Here is a link to test:

http://www.legendaily.com/whatshot/zuckerwatte_dance_mmmmhhh_hungry_http_www_chilloutzone_net_video_zuckerwatte-jackson-2_html-309734

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Facebook has limited the thumbnails on a post to 3 (You can choose from 3):

  - The first one is og:image by default
  - the other two are from the body tag
- Most of your Posts `og:image` `content` are smaller than the limited
  size which is 200PX by 200PX, that why facebook chooses a fall back image from the body tag.

For example the URL to gave in your question, Here's what I have found:

- `<meta property="og:image"
  content="http://i.legendaily.com/uploads/52405912d7c94.jpg" />`   Dimensions: 150px × 90px
- These two are the og:image fallback:

  - on line 77 `<img class="logo" src="http://i.legendaily.com/img/ld_w.png">`
  - on line 140 `<img src="http://i.legendaily.com/img/ld.png" class="logo">`
- Your website HTML ***source is completely broken***

  - There's Two closing `</head>` tags the first one on `line 54` and the other on `line 123`
  - There's non-head tags they are actually in the head tags, `div`, `script` (fine but not good for SEO), `p`..etc..
- I hope that I helped you not only with Facebook open graph protocol but with your Site source, so try to fix them as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you @AdamZapp :) The head-tag was a bug from the last release, so good find. Actually both of your found bugs are the same, there was just a head-tag way too low in the code.
I find it incredible from FB to pretend they know better which images should be shared. Thanks anyway!