# Open Graph for Facebook sharing picks wrong image

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I am using Open Graph for image sharing but it picks up the wrong image that I’ve already deleted from the database. In the Inspect Element tab of Web Inspector, it shows the correct image path but it does not share the correct image.

PHP code:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML, Meta Tags, Metadata" />
<meta name="description" content="Profile Share by user." />
<meta name="author" content="I" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="http://mydocs.com/">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="User profile">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="<?php echo $SITE_PATH.$meta_userimage;?>" />
<meta property="og:title"content="User profile" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $SITE_PATH.$meta_userimage;>"/>
```

I’ve already referred to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977661/facebook-shares-wrong-image-thumbnail) but it doesn’t help me.

Comment: got to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and check what facebook scraping from your page

Comment: @ Ashish I use this and got some issue:Inferred Property The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.    Meta Tag <meta property="og:title" content="User profile" />
Meta Tag <meta property="og:image" content="$site_url/upload/1413203307_abc-blocks.jpg" />

Answer (score 1):

When Facebook queries the open graph data for a page, it gets cached until you flush it or 24 hours are up.

If you visit [this facebook debug page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and try scraping the page; you will find an option to refresh the scrape by clicking the "Fetch new scrape information" button

Comment: I used the debugger tool but refresh option was not found.It gives og:url and og:description warning.It also gives image size problem but after i give the static path of image size was 200x200 but it again give different image

Comment: have you been through the following facebook page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices
?